# Only exact with wildcard matching and proximity using Sphinx Search Engine (API-PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard, sphinx

I have this huge problem properly configuring Sphinx, I have an index of name, tags and cat_tags. I would like return extended matches, e.g.

if I type "eng" I should receive all records matching "*eng*", so:
engine, english, boateng (for any indexed field) would be inlucded within the query result. How should I configure my index and my PHP-API in order to get desired result? Also how should the exact query look, taking *$phrase* being a phrase we are looking for (one or more words, we need all perfect matches along with possible matches - just like search hinting would give us).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default sphinx indexes whole words - as per `charset_table`.

To match part words look at `min_infix_len`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len

enable it along with `expand keywords`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-expand-keywords

Comment: Well, thank You, I've tried all these options and I couldn't sort it out properly. I'll try to follow Your suggestions. Does it have much impact on the performance? It's actually going to be used in search hints, therefore it can't be too slow. What about min_prefix_len? And how should I configure them? Should I both set to 1??